# What are the concurrency (multithreading) implementation changes over different versions of JDK?

Tags: java, java-8

What are the concurrency (multithreading) implementation changes over different versions of JDK? How exactly it differs from JDK 4/5 with JDK 7/8?

Comment: The changes are documented. Further, you will find tons of related tutorials in the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from 5, concurrency package has been added. Before that it was available as third party library.

Look at this URL for 8 changes
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/changes8.html

Also look at this URL for 7 changes
http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/07/concurrency-java-se-7